# String in a struct, lifetime

Tags: rust

I know what the difference between these 3 struct is - a lifetime of `a`

```
struct S1 {
    a: &'static str,
    b: int
}

struct S2<'aa> {
    a: &'aa str,
    b: int
}

struct S3 {
    a: String,
    b: int
}

fn main() {
    let s1 = S1 {a: "123", b: 123};
    let s2 = S2 {a: "123", b: 123};
    let s3 = S2 {a: "123".into_owned(), b: 123};
}
```

Could you show me a use case of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd, in other words, when is it better to use the 1st over 2nd and 3rd, when - 2nd over 1st and 3rd, etc? In the documentation there's no explanation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**`S1`**: This only allows you to use string literals, or other strings with a `static` (i.e. they can never be deallocated) lifetime.

**`S2`**: This lets you use arbitrary string slices, provided they have an expressible lifetime.  For example, you cannot return dynamic instances of `S2` from an `Iterator`, because there's no way to express the lifetime involved.  That said, this allows you to avoid unnecessary heap allocations.

**`S3`**: The most general, since it owns its contents, but requires heap allocation to use.

Comment: which one is used mostly? do you have example of when to do use them?

Comment: `S2` is the most performant, `S1` is as fast, easier to reason about, but far more restrictive, `S3` is the slowest, but easy to reason about.  Use `S2` if you can, `S1`/`S3` if you have to.  If you want examples... just find string-handling Rust code and read that.  I can't think of anything that would be short and not uselessly contrived.